# how to show images in html content in recyclerview adapter?

Tags: android

i get images in html content with retrofit and its work good :
this get a single post:

```
    private  void postContentRequest (){
    APIInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
    Call<Post> call = apiInterface.getPostContent();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                Post post = response.body();
                username.setText(post.getUsername());
                date.setText(post.getDate());
                     final Spannable html = (Spannable)Html.fromHtml(post.getContent(),new MyImageGetter(PostContent.this, postcontent),null);
                postcontent.setText(html);
                postcontent.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Post> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
        }
    });

}
```

i want get list of posts by recylcerview adapter :

```
    private  void List<Post>ContentRequest (){
    APIInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
    Call<List<Post>> call = apiInterface.getPostContent();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                List<Post> posts =  response.body();
                setupRecyclerView(posts);

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<Post>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
        }
    });

}
```

and show with recyclerview adapter :

```
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
    holder.username.setText(posts.get(position).getUsername());
    holder.date.setText(posts.get(position).getDate());
    Spannable html = (Spannable) Html.fromHtml(posts.get(position).getContent(),new ImageGetter(context, holder.postcontent),null);
    holder.postcontent.setText(html);
    }
```

but it dont show images. 
please help.
thanks

Comment: what did you mean in HTML content here

Comment: post content that has html tags like text, img and ...

Comment: can you share that

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
Spannable html = (Spannable) Html.fromHtml(posts.get(position).getContent(),new ImageGetter(context, holder.postcontent), null);
        holder.postcontent.setText(html);
```

It seems like you are **setting text instead of Image** to your holder.

Instead of those, if you're trying to show an image, use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library then declare it like this:

```
Glide.with(myContext).load(posts.get(position).getImage())  // Just an example, it depends on your posts and image declaration
     .into(holder.postcontent.yourImageViewinHolder) 
}
```

This will only work when `posts.get(position).getImage() != null` and you're getting the right url-image.

Comment: in post content There is not only one image. There may be  many image in the content. glide is for one image into imageview. there is not imageview. textview that i want show html content.

Comment: That's why I used: `posts.get(position)` - `holder.postcontent.yourImageViewinHolder` to check if there are any images available to set into the `ImageView` or etc. However, the way you were setting is not correct. You can also, get the all images first, then setting them into `ImageView`. I'm suspecting that you're trying to set a text from `ImageView` which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

In android there is a lovely class android.text.HTML that processes HTML strings into displayable styled text. Currently android doesn’t support all HTML tags.

You have to use Webview instance of Textview.

Comment: in the first code it works well.and show images in content.

Comment: post the code : ImageGetter and MyImageGetter class